# Python: finding how many maximum, choosing a specific one. Etc

Tags: python, tuples

So basically, what I am in need of help with is a part of a program I am working on:

```
   votes = (a tuple with elements such as: 11222, 1314, 551, 555)
   given_seats = (a tuple with elements ie: 0, 1, 0, 4)

   first_maximum = max(votes)
   first_maximum_position = votes.index(max(votes))

    for another_maximum in range(len(votes)):
        if another_maximum != first_maximum_position
            if another_maximum == first_maximum
                if given_seats.index(another_maximum) < given_seats.index(first_maximum_position):
                    first_maximum_position = outro_max
```

That part would be this one. I without entering into details about what which funtions do. What I am trying to acomplish is: First, find a maximum within a tuple and the position that maximum is at. After getting that information I need to check the other elements of that tupple one by one, to see if there is any other element of that same tuple that has the same value has that maximum.

If there aren't any other elements with the same value as the found maximum, the function will proceed to do some calculations (which is working fine). On the other hand, if other elements of the tuple are found that have the same value as the maximum, I want to know it's position, so that I can check on a different tupple if a certain condition is met and if it is, I want that last maximum to replace the one that was found first.

It's a little hard to explain, but this is the best I can do.

Best regards

Comment: Please edit this to clarify what your code is supposed to do.  The single example is not enough to describe the desired function, and your low-level code description does not have enough defined referents to make sense.

Comment: It's only hard to explain because you haven't produced a minimal example!

Answer (score 1):

The first bit is easy if you use `enumerate` to get both index and value at the same time.

```
import operator

max_idx, max_val = max(enumerate(votes), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
# operator.itemgetter(1) is equivalent to lambda x: x[1]
```

The second bit sounds like you should be using a `Counter`, but you could do it the long way if you like.

```
max_values = [(idx, val) for idx,val in enumerate(votes) if val==max_val]
# a list of ALL values that match max_val, including by necessity max_val
```